# Check if Xml Element exists before/during a foreach loop

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, foreach, var

I started learning C# this month and I'm creating a program to parse XML file and get some data. The .xml file is:

```
<Info>
<Symbols>
<Symbol>
    <Name>Name</Name>
    <Type>INT</Type>
</Symbol>
<Symbol>
    <Name>Name</Name>
    <Type>INT</Type>
    <Properties>
        <Property>
            <Name>TAG</Name>
        </Property>
    </Properties>
</Symbol>
</Symbols>
</Info>
```

My code below, gets values from elements "Name" and "Type", from "Symbol". But I need to check if the element "Properties" exists in each "Symbol", because, as you can see, there will be some (like the first "Symbol") without the "Properties" element.
If it exists, I will get the value from , in this case: "TAG".
Is there a simple way to make the foreach try to get it only if it exists?!

```
var symbols = from symbol in RepDoc.Element("Info").Element("Symbols").Descendants("Symbol")          

select new
{
VarName = symbol.Element("Name").Value,
VarType = symbol.Element("Type").Value,
};

foreach (var symbol in symbols) 
{
Console.WriteLine("" symbol.VarName + "\t" + symbol.VarType);
}
```

Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res = XDocument.Load(fname)
            .Descendants("Symbol")
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                Type = (string)x.Element("Type"),
                Props = x.Descendants("Property")
                       .Select(p => (string)p.Element("Name"))
                       .ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
```

`Props` will have zero or more elements depending on the `Properties` tag.